# How to put callbacks function in Observables in Rxjs?

Tags: google-maps, angular, ionic2, rxjs

**Scenario**

I am developing an Ionic2 app using Angular2 in which user select location within his country. Which is working fine. I am using google [Place Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) for this. But I want to use some methods of this API in Observables by using Rxjs in my app.

Below is my current code which is working fine:

**Home.html**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="autocomplete.query" [showCancelButton]="true" (ionInput)="updateSearch()"></ion-searchbar>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of autocompleteItems" tappable (click)="chooseItem(item)">
  {{ item }}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**Home.ts**

```
city: string;
address;
autocompleteItems;
autocomplete;
service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService(); 

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, platform: Platform, private zone: NgZone) {
this.city = "Karachi";
this.autocompleteItems = [];
this.autocomplete = {
  query: ''
};
this.address = {
  place: ''
}
}



chooseItem(item: any) {
    item.split[','];
    console.log(item);
    this.autocomplete.query = item[1];
}

updateSearch() {
    if (this.autocomplete.query == '') {
    this.autocompleteItems = [];
    return;
}

let me = this;

this.service.getPlacePredictions({ 
    input: this.autocomplete.query, componentRestrictions: {country: 'PK'} 
  }, function (predictions, status) {
  me.autocompleteItems = []; 
  me.zone.run(function () {
    if(predictions != null){
        predictions.forEach(function (prediction) {
        me.autocompleteItems.push(prediction.description);
      });
    }
    else {
      return;
    }
  });
});
}
```

**Problem**

After converting above code in Observables its shows me an error on `Property 'getPlacePredictions' does not exist on type '{}'.` Please help me on this scenario that How can I convert above `update()` function code in Rxjs Observables.

Below is my convertable code:

```
ngOnInit() {
Observable.from(this.service).map((data) => {
  return data.getPlacePredictions({ 
    input: this.autocomplete.query, componentRestrictions: {country: 'PK'} 
  }, (predictions, status) => {
      return predictions;
  })
 }).subscribe(console.log) //Final Results}
}
```

Comment: I guess you have to add type hinting (cast it to `any`) for the compiler: `Observable.from(this.service).map((data: any) => {`. I believe it's also an option in the TypeScript compiler you can turn off, but I'm not sure which one it was again :)

Comment: @PierreDuc After cast it. I am getting this error in my console window `TypeError: object is not observable`

Comment: Looking at your code, I suggest you read a bit more about the inner workings of typescript/angular and rxjs. You've got some odd things in your code, and it's difficult to understand. You can only use `Observable.from` on an array like object. I strongly doubt the `this.service` is an array. On the other hand you are using `let me = this`, which is completely unnecessary in TypeScript if you use arrow functions, instead of the `function` keyword

Comment: @PierreDuc I copy `update()` function code from here [google-maps-autocomplete-for-ionic-2-applications](http://devfanaticblog.com/google-maps-autocomplete-for-ionic-2-applications/). Thats why I want to convert above code into Rxjs Observable.

Comment: I don't understand why you are putting your service in observable?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

link: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindCallback

```
let getPlaces = Obserable.bindCallback(this.service.getPlacePredictions)

getPlaces({ 
  input: this.autocomplete.query, componentRestrictions: {country: 'PK'} 
}). subscribe(predictions, status) => {
  console.log(predictions, status);
})
```